# Datediff function results in overflow only in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, common-table-expression, datediff

I have 2 tables with records that I'm trying to join based on a date column. Because of the precision of the date column, they are not exactly the same, so I came up with a method for joining the records in one table to the record with the closest date in another table (Only if the dates are within 1 minute of each other). I've run this on several tables with success, however I've recently come across some data that causes the Datediff SQL function to result in an overflow.

Here's the relevant data I'm working with:

```
---------------   #tmp_Job_Queue   ---------------
SELECT * INTO #tmp_Job_Queue
FROM (
SELECT N'130' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2006-12-28 14:37:24.717' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'133' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2007-01-09 15:42:43.500' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'219' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2008-01-08 14:52:52.797' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'234' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2008-02-15 17:00:40.440' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'278' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2008-12-23 11:14:06.420' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'281' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2008-12-23 15:14:51.797' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'286' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2009-01-21 14:46:16.367' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'288' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2009-01-22 10:33:21.150' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'290' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2009-01-26 08:18:22.527' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'340' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2009-12-30 14:58:17.193' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'349' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2010-01-19 12:40:26.190' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'390' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2010-12-21 11:25:50.057' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'399' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2011-01-25 15:44:59.673' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'440' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2011-12-19 08:40:41.547' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL 
SELECT N'447' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2012-01-12 14:15:00.800' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'563' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2013-12-19 14:39:39.123' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'569' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2014-01-13 11:26:27.007' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'631' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2014-12-16 10:07:53.907' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'639' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2015-01-08 16:10:50.010' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'689' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2015-12-17 13:43:28.687' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'691' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2015-12-18 12:15:18.367' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'699' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2016-01-12 12:27:09.523' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'794' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2017-10-09 14:58:06.503' AS [DateCompleted] UNION ALL
SELECT N'817' AS [ID], N'Process 1' AS [ProcessName], N'2017-10-12 08:54:57.820' AS [DateCompleted] ) t;

---------------   #tmp_Log   ---------------
SELECT * INTO #tmp_Log
FROM (
SELECT N'5' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2008-02-15 17:00:39.550' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'190' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2017-10-09 14:58:05.383' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'191' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2017-10-12 08:54:57.820' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'17' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2009-01-21 14:46:15.150' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'18' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2009-01-21 16:24:20.913' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'19' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2009-01-22 10:33:19.777' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'33' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2010-01-19 12:40:24.710' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'41' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2010-12-21 11:25:47.360' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'60' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2011-12-19 08:40:38.167' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'67' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2012-01-12 14:14:58.773' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'79' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2012-12-17 15:49:49.890' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'84' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2013-01-07 08:57:58.957' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'21' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2009-01-26 08:18:21.213' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'47' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2011-01-25 15:44:57.760' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'96' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2013-12-19 14:39:25.513' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'102' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2014-01-13 11:26:22.107' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'114' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2014-12-16 10:07:32.987' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'121' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2015-01-08 16:10:45.110' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'135' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2015-12-17 13:43:23.220' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'137' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2015-12-18 12:15:15.577' AS [CreateDate] UNION ALL
SELECT N'145' AS [ID], N'Process 2' AS [ProcessName], N'2016-01-12 12:27:07.797' AS [CreateDate] ) t;
```

And here's the query I've been using to get the records with the closest dates:

```
DECLARE @QProcess VARCHAR(50) = 'Process 1'
DECLARE @LProcess VARCHAR(50) = 'Process 2'

;WITH timeDifferences AS (
    SELECT  Q.ID AS QueueID, L.ID AS LogID,
            ABS(DATEDIFF(MS, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted)) AS DiffInMS
    FROM    #tmp_Job_Queue AS Q
    JOIN    #tmp_Log       AS L
      ON    Q.ProcessName = @QProcess AND
            L.ProcessName = @LProcess AND
            ABS(DATEDIFF(MI, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted)) <= 1
)
SELECT *
FROM   timeDifferences AS T1
WHERE  DiffInMS = (SELECT MIN(DiffInMS) FROM timeDifferences AS T2 WHERE T2.QueueID = T1.QueueID)
```

Usually it works, but with this particular set of data it's giving me an error. If I take out the WHERE clause, it works with no problem, but as soon as I put it back in (even if I do something simple like `WHERE DiffInMS = 0` it starts giving this error:

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

I can change it to use some intermediate temp tables and get it to run:

```
DECLARE @QProcess VARCHAR(50) = 'Process 1'
DECLARE @LProcess VARCHAR(50) = 'Process 2'

;WITH timeDifferences AS (
    SELECT  Q.ID AS QueueID, L.ID AS LogID,
            ABS(DATEDIFF(MS, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted)) AS DiffInMS
    FROM    #tmp_Job_Queue AS Q
    JOIN    #tmp_Log       AS L
      ON    Q.ProcessName = @QProcess AND
            L.ProcessName = @LProcess AND
            ABS(DATEDIFF(MI, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted)) <= 1
)
SELECT *
INTO   #unfilteredDifferences
FROM   timeDifferences

SELECT  *
FROM    #unfilteredDifferences AS T1
where   DiffInMS = (SELECT MIN(DiffInMS) FROM #unfilteredDifferences AS T2 WHERE T2.QueueID = T1.QueueID)
```

So it's more of an annoyance than anything. I'm assuming it has something to do with how SQL Server processes CTEs. Can anybody explain why this is happening for me?

**EDIT**

More specifically, why is it that I do not get an overflow error when I remove the WHERE clause, but reintroducing the WHERE clause causes the error? I looked up the SQL order of operations and confirmed that JOIN is evaluated before SELECT, so that should get rid of rows where the datediff is greater than 1 minute. Then the Datediff(MS, ....) wouldn't execute for rows that would cause the overflow. Or at least, that's how I thought it should work?

Also, I would expect that the error would still be encountered when I remove the WHERE clause since all rows would be evaluated, but that doesn't seem to be what is happening.

Comment: If, for whatever reason, you did need exact values, you could break your datetimes into smaller units to do the datetime arithmetic without overflow. For example, `CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted) > 2 THEN CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted) AS BIGINT) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, L.CreateDate, DATEADD(DAY, -DATEDIFF(DAY, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted), Q.DateCompleted)) ELSE DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted) END` (so break it up into days and milliseconds).

Answer (score 1):

The only part of the your query that can generate the overflow error is:

```
ABS(DATEDIFF(MS, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted)) AS DiffInMS
```

I don't think your range of dates is large enough for any of the "minute" differences to cause a problem.  SQL Server 2016 solves this problem with `datediff_big()`.  Nice to know the issue has finally been addressed.

Why do you only see this sometimes?  My guess is that you are not processing *all* the data.  If you did an `order by` in the outer query, you would probably always see the problem.  It is probably buried in some row deep down.

If I were to guess that you don't care about large diffs, you can replace the logic with something like:

```
(CASE WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(minute, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted)) < 2000000000 / (60 * 1000)
      THEN ABS(DATEDIFF(MS, L.CreateDate, Q.DateCompleted))
 ELSE) AS DiffInMS
```

This will only do the difference when it is safe.  This version returns `NULL`, but you could just as easily include:

```
     ELSE 2000000000
```

If you wanted an upper bound.

Comment: This answer and the anwser by @russ both suggest using CASE statements to avoid overflow, which makes sense. However, what I really want to know (and I'll edit my question to clarify) is why the query works without an overflow error when I omit the WHERE clause, but gives me an error when the WHERE clause is reintroduced? Please see my edited question

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns  out that the query you have got has to check 487 rows against each other. Perhaps some of those are huge numbers of Milliseconds between the CreateDate and the DateCompleted. However, only 18 of them are under a minute so I combined the two DATEDIFFs into a CASE statement which means that the CTE can run the query probably by eliminating rows where the DATEDIFF is bigger than a minute *before* it processes the SELECT statement at the end.

```
DECLARE @QProcess VARCHAR(50) = 'Process 1'
DECLARE @LProcess VARCHAR(50) = 'Process 2'

;WITH timeDifferences AS (
    SELECT  Q.ID AS QueueID, L.ID AS LogID,
    CASE WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(MI,L.CreateDate,Q.DateCompleted)) <= 1 
    THEN ABS(DATEDIFF(MS,L.CreateDate,Q.DateCompleted)) END AS DiffInMS
FROM    #tmp_Job_Queue AS Q
JOIN    #tmp_Log       AS L
  ON    Q.ProcessName = @QProcess AND
        L.ProcessName = @LProcess
)
SELECT * FROM timeDifferences AS T1 
WHERE  DiffInMS = (SELECT MIN(DiffInMS) FROM timeDifferences AS T2
WHERE T2.QueueID = T1.QueueID)
GO
```

You will get a Warning in Messages regarding elimination of NULLS...as far as I know this just means that the CASE statement produced a lot of NULL rows. These rows were then eliminated from the result set and that's what the warning is saying. It would be wise to test it against your #Temp table query.

Comment: See my comment on Gordon's answer and my edited question

Comment: I don't have enough technical knowledge of exactly how CTE and DATEDIFF function together to answer the question properly. What I'd consider is that the WHERE clause at the end most likely doubles the size of the result set in memory to compare the QueueIDs. Whilst the CASE statement nullifies the DiffInMS value for anything above a minute (and those rows are stored as nulls), without it those rows are duplicated in the memory with each DifIinMS as a number. That's despite the fact that most of them are not presented to us.

Comment: Probably that is just the end of the memory that a combination of DATEDIFF and the CTE can bag from the RAM. I think I'd need to refer to a Microsoft engineer for a more definite answer than this.

Comment: CTE certainly uses memory differently from a #temp table. I get the idea it functions something similar to a trigger.